# How to have two update methods in resource controller laravel 6

Tags: laravel, laravel-6

This is my user controller where I need two updates

```
public function index(){}

public function create(){}

public function store(Request $request){}

public function show($id){}

public function edit($id){}

public function update(Request $request, $id){}

public function destroy($id){}

public function update_something_else(Request $request, $id){}
```

This is my web.php file

```
Route::resource('FleetAdmin', 'FleetAdminController')->middleware('auth');
```

This is my view

```
action="{{ route('FleetAdmin.update_something_else', $user->id) }}"
```

Comment: you can use if/else condition inside your update method and write your logic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to define another route for this

```
Route::post('FleetAdmin/update_something_else/{id}', ['as'=>'FleetAdmin.update_something_else', 'uses'=>'FleetAdminController@update_something_else'])->middleware('auth');
```

Answer (score 0):

Ressource support only default functions provided in controllers, in your case you need to define a new route like :
`Route::Put('fleetadmins/{fleetadmin}/updatesomethingelse', 'FleetAdminController@update_something_else')->name('fleetadmin.update_something_else');`

Note that you can't use `Put('fleetadmins/{fleetadmin})` cause it's already used by `public function update(Request $request, $id)`